# Is the referent of "which" clear?

Tags: reference

My freelancer wrote the below sentence. I asked him if it is clear what "which" refers to? Does it refer to "all modes of transport" or "4,740 miles"? He wrote another version for me without telling me if this version is clear. Can you tell me whether the referent of "which" is clear?

> In 1985, people in England travelled an average of 4,740 miles using
> all modes of transport, which significantly increased to 6,475 miles
> in 2000.

[image]

Comment: It refers to the entire clause that precedes it.

Comment: thank you, @BillJ. How can I know if "which" refers to the entire clause that precedes it or the figure 4,740 miles since they both can increase?

Comment: It will certainly be understood as the older figure rising to the newer figure. It's not very elegant but it's unambiguous.

Comment: A parse shows it: In 1985, people in England travelled an average of 4,740 miles using all modes of transport. This average using all modes of transport increased significantly to 6,475 miles in 2000.

Comment: which makes sense? "4,740 miles increased to 6,475 miles" or "all modes of transport increased to 6,475 miles"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to "4,740 miles". It must, since only a distance can increase to a distance. (The sentence says that it "increased to 6,475 miles"). The difficulty arises because the relative clause is not adjacent to its referent; it has been "extraposed from its noun phrase". (Araucaria gives an explanation of that phenomenon at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253496/meaning-of-and-the-day-came-when/253550#253550 .) I hope that your freelancer's revision was clearer!